# How can I make a split-text inside the input placeholder?

Tags: input

i have one doubt. How can i make a split content (one content is permanent & another one is hide while typing the field) inside the text field using place holder?

Comment: With what programming language you want?

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are developing for the web...You can accomplish what you want using AngularJS [ngShow](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and [ngHide](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide).